# Count files in multiple folder and display the number into in excel file cel in front of the path Given

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to know how many files there are in Multiple folder with .pdf extension. I read hundreds of examples with message boxes, but that is not what I'm looking for. I just want to have the number displayed into cell next to every path provided in excel. Basically I need a loop which pick the path from excel file and get count from the path and paste the count in front of that path.

Sub sample()

```
Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
FolderPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\*"

path = FolderPath & "\*.pdf"

Filename = Dir(path)

Do While Filename <> ""
   count = count + 1
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

Range("A2").Value = count
'MsgBox count & " : files found in folder"
```

End Sub

Comment: try search `FileSystemObject` for more reference.

Comment: If you don't mind could you please write some code for me.

Answer (score 0):

The link below demo could be help of you.
https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/list-files-in-folder-and-subfolders-with-vba-filesystemobject/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way with only five steps!

1) In the VBA Project, add a Module.

2) Go to Menu > Tools > References and add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

3) Add a variable on the top of the created module

```vba
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

4) Create the Function:

```vba
Public Function COUNTFILES(ByVal directory As String, ByVal ext As String) As Long

Dim total_files As Long
Dim i As File

If directory = "" Or ext = "" Then
    COUNTFILES = 0
    Exit Function
End If

For Each i In fso.GetFolder(directory).FILES

    If InStr(1, i.Name, ext) > 0 Then

        total_files = total_files + 1

    End If

Next

COUNTFILES = total_files

End Function
```

5) Now, you can use in the sheet the VBA Function just like you use the built-in Functions, typing with the equals sign inside cell.

```vba
=COUNTFILES("THE CELL WHERE IS THE DIRETORY PATH",".pdf")
```

Comment: Not able to run code, Where I have put the path of the directory, Step 5 not understandable

Comment: In the desired sheet, include at A column the list of all directories, at the B column, type the code described on step 5. Your code should looks like it: =COUNTFILES(A2;".pdf")